# Implementation of API client with SWIFT using Alamofire and rxSwift

Tags: json, swift, api, alamofire, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement solution from http://kean.github.io/post/api-client which I really like, but I've encountered some problems.
The source code is here: https://github.com/gentoo-pl/ApiTest

The problem is in [Model/Client.swift:52](https://github.com/gentoo-pl/ApiTest/blob/de9d3d6f0474a290fa57b501a0ba97d9ae4c88c8/ApiTest/Model/Client.swift#L52) - *Type 'JSON' (aka 'Any') has no member ' init '*

and in the file [Model/API/ApiDev.swift:16](https://github.com/gentoo-pl/ApiTest/blob/de9d3d6f0474a290fa57b501a0ba97d9ae4c88c8/ApiTest/Model/API/ApiDev.swift#L16) - *Generic parameter 'Response' could not be inferred*

I'm not experienced in SWIFT yet and apologize if these are trivial mistakes but thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: JSON is probably object from Mapper library, you need to check what did change since this code was written

Comment: Many thanks @Lu_ for your suggestions but I did not find any major changes for my problem in Mapper library

Comment: You need to use yours JSON mapper there, in article was just an example, you need to add it yourselve, add SwityJSON and delete that typealias JSON